# Evaluation parameter in knn

Tags: regression, k-nn

I am using KNN for a regression task

It's like that:

1- I normalized the data

2- I calculated the distance of the new data with the previous data (Euclidean distance)

3 - I choose k nearest neighbors

4- I calculated the appropriate weight for the distance of each neighbor

5-  **value= I calculated the dot product of the distances & weights  (which gives a specific number)**

**6- I evaluate the result of this value with the normalized average of each data (threshold ) to see how far or close it is from this value.**

example:

```
threshold = ( sum_of_featur1_normal/N + sum_of_featur2_normal/N + sum_of_featur3_normal/N +...) /number_of_features 
Percentage change= |threshold -value| / threshold
```

7- and By checking the Percentage change, I estimate how close we were to the desired state

Now my question is whether this method of using the average value mentioned in step 6 is correct or not and do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: can you share the full code to help follow your steps?

Comment: @Justtrying  Actually, I haven't implemented it yet and I am checking theoretically

Comment: Have you checked the scikit-learn implementation?
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor, it is widely used and might help understand the steps